# nouveau error while booting arch

Tags: graphics, window, boot, archlinux, bios

I dual booted arch linux with window 8.1. After installation, while booting for the first time, this error occurred.

```
Here is the error I found.
{ [0.063411] Ignoring BGRT: Invalid status 0 (expected 1)
starting version 218
Arch_Linux: clean, 70622/18677760 files, 1643393/74703025 blocks
[    15.759913] nouveau E[  PIBUST][0000:01:00.0] HUBO: 0xffffffff (0x1a
[    15.759952] nouveau E[  PIBUST][0000:01:00.0] GPCO: 0x00000001 (0x1a
[    15.823494] nouveau E[    PBUS][0000:01:00.0] MMIO: 0x00000000 FAULT a
[    15.824050] nouveau E[     DRM]Pointer to TMDS table invalid
[    15.824072] nouveau E[     DRM]Pointer to flat panel table invalid}
```

Comment: I have the same problem with an Ubuntu installation

Comment: Did you followed [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nouveau#Installation) ? Please make sure [Xorg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg)  is proprelly installed.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps helped me resolve a similar issue.

1. add the boot parameter 'nomodeset' to grub at boot. To do this, press e over the Linux option on the grub menu. Then add 'nomodeset' before the 'quiet splash'.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> to continue booting.

This stops the graphics driver from getting loaded prior to booting into Linux.

If this doesn't work, remove the 'quiet splash' so you can inspect the messages at boot.

In my case, one of my drives had errors that needed fsck to fix. Fixing the drive errors let me boot without issues.
Hope this helps someone.